# Entity diagram for student management

Tags: database-design

I am creating a database for a student management system. The system have the following requirements:

- Students enroll classes
- For every class, a student must be evaluated with multiple scores (projects, quizzes, homework, etc.) and a final exam.

I created this entity relation diagram:
[image]
And This is the SQL schema
[image]
However, I think that in the `scores` the `testName` and `testWeight` attributes are redundancy as these attributes are the same for every student with same `classCode`. How can I remove this redundancy.

P.s: The two pictures just a part of my design.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I think that in the `scores` the `testName` and `testWeight` attributes are redundancy as these attributes are the same for every student with same `classCode`. How can I remove this redundancy.

1. Add a `tests` table that stores a unique list of `tests` and has a one-to-many relationship with `scores`.
2. Store the `testId` in the `scores` table as a foreign key to the primary key `testId` in the `tests` table.
3. Move the `testName` and `testWeight` columns to the `tests` table.