# Many to many relationship in ER diagram

Tags: database-design

I am working with a database system with following requirements:

- A student can enroll many classes
- A classes can have many students
- For every class, a student must be evaluated with multiple scores (projects, quizzes, homework, etc.) and a final exam.

The relationship between `students` and `classes` entities is many-to-many. Can the `scores` entity  have a relationship with the many-to-many relationship between `students` and `classes` entities. It means that the `scores` in rdms will have foreign key to `studentId` and `classId` in the many-to-many relationship

Or should I create a weak entity as two one-to-many relationship between `students` and `classes`.

Should I go for
[image]

or

[image]

Comment: What happened to [tests](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/320681/150011)?

Comment: I reviewed the last post and I think that it is better to have score entity link to many-to-many relationship (although I don't know if this is possible in ER diagram). Of course the test still their but I think that it is not relevant so I don't include that here

Comment: `Score` is one-to-many though, as each instance of a `Test`'s `Score` is unique to that `Student`. I.e. no two `Student`s can share the same `Score` row.

Comment: But the many-to-many relationship between `students` and `classes` will converted into a table (called ```student-class```) with `studentId`  and `classId ` attributes. I want the score can have foreign key to these attribute of `student-class `as a student can have score if he enroll a class only. However I don't know how to express this in ER diagram